# Don't know why I'm getting Error Code 10022 (Invalid Argument) when setting socket options in my C# sniffer

Tags: c#, sockets, packet-sniffers

I'm writing a packet sniffer as an exercise in learning .Net 4 socket development on in C#.  My goal is to sniff IP packets coming in and out out my computer.

My problem is that I'm getting error code 10022, invalid argument, on my call to SetSocketOption.  I don't see where I have an invalid argument.  I have some admin privs on my computer, but perhaps I don't have enough.  It's my work computer and the IT department is pretty strict.  With that said, if it was a permissions problem I would expect a different exception.

I'm not sure what my next step should be to debug this problem.  Anyone have an idea?

Here's the code follows:

```
public Sniffer()
{
    try
    {
        socket = new Socket(
            AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);

        IPAddress[] ipAddresses = Dns.GetHostEntry(
            Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList;

        socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ipAddresses[0], 0));

        socket.SetSocketOption(
            SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);

        byte[] inputData = new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
        byte[] outValue = new byte[4];

        socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, inputData, outValue);
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        string ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see IP as one of the arguments in this documentation (?) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/600stss7.aspx

Comment: Are you running win7 or vista?  If that's the case you might just need to elevate privileges.

Comment: Win7.  Any idea how I find what level I need to get to?

Comment: @Shoban  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketoptionlevel.aspx is the reference to SocketOptionLevel.

Comment: Try running the app under admin mode. in Win 7 even if you are running as an admin user by default they are run with standard account mode.

Comment: @Shoban, tried that, didn't make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: You may see more specific error information in your Windows event viewer since this is coming from some Windows system error. FWIW, here's the native code when you set socket options: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/6b5ef121ebea45b14f489a177e2e3f27fce86781/src/System.Net.Sockets/src/System/Net/Sockets/SocketPal.Windows.cs#L394-L414

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has restricted the use of raw sockets on non-server editions of the the windows OS on all OS's newer than XP SP2, due to abuse by viruses in the early 2000's.

You can read more on what restrictions are in place from the page on [TCP/IP Raw Sockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548(v=vs.85).aspx) on the MSDN.

Answer (score -2):

WSAEINVAL 10022

Invalid argument.

Some invalid argument was supplied (for example, specifying an invalid level to the setsockopt function). In some instances, it also refers to the current state of the socket—for instance, calling accept on a socket that is not listening.

Take a look about this error here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I'm using System.Net.Sockets.  The link you point to is about Windows Socket 2 which I think is for c/c++ logic.  Sorry, I'm new to the microsoft socket world, so my comment may be naive.

Comment: @Martin JAsper: Take a look here: someone else had fixed the problem: http://sharedcache.codeplex.com/workitem/5002

Comment: @JAiro: I gave it a try.  The socket is available right after the bind.  So that doesn't appear to be the issue.

Comment: here in this post said something about the antivirus If you have time check it http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/2562a03a-9cd9-4812-9137-cfc195d7f281

Comment: @JAiro: that's an interesting thought.  I want to disable McAfee so I can test, but I can't at work.  I think I'm going to have to try this at home.  I will say, however, that I can run WireShark and it captures packets without issue.  It's using WinPcap for link level access and is unmanaged code.

Comment: @JAiro: btw, thank you very much for your efforts, they are most helpful.