# Why do I get SocketException 10022 when setting SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded to true?

Tags: c#, sockets, socketexception

I have done quite a bit of searching on this topic and I am not having much luck.  My situation is very similar to [Don't know why I'm getting Error Code 10022 (Invalid Argument) when setting socket options in my C# sniffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145923/dont-know-why-im-getting-error-code-10022-invlid-argument-when-setting-soc).  However, the answers given there have not helped me resolve the problem.

The code that is giving me trouble is:

```
var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontLinger, true);
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true); \\ SocketException thrown here
```

A SocketException with error number 10022 is being thrown on the line that is setting HeaderIncluded.  I didn't write this code and I had assumed that this was production code that had been tested.  So at this point I am thinking it is my computer.  However, I don't want to go down the wrong path here nor am I asking anyone to code this for me.  Just some guidance before I go insane would be greatly appreciated.

I have ruled out the following even though I thought they were a long shot:

1. Perhaps HeaderIncluded is not available for a ProtocolType.Tcp
   and that needs to be ProtocolType.IP.  Tested this and still get the
   error.
2. Perhaps socket type needs to be SocketType.Raw.  Tested
   this and still get the error.
3. Have tried doing a
   GetSocketOption for HeaderIncluded and get the same SocketException.
4. If I comment out this one socket option line, code works great.

It is in the back of my mind that the code is just wrong, but the fact that I am coming to this code after it supposedly has been tested and deployed has me thinking otherwise.  If you hear hooves, think horses and not zebras kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C), under "Capturing the Packets" heading (if you haven't seen it already).

Two things that differ:

1. The example uses a raw socket (`SocketType.Raw`). Yours uses `SocketType.Stream`.
2. The example calls `bind` on the socket prior to setting the option. Yours (at least in code you provide) doesn't.

Based on my experience, both of these differences are highly probable causes of the 10022 error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);` only works for raw sockets, I wrote an example that works for me. Note that I did have to use administrator privileges.

```
var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Seqpacket, ProtocolType.Tcp);

socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontLinger, true);
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

this is working code:

var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, 1);

Comment: Can you explain why you think this would help?

Comment: Edited my answer. Microsoft says what "HeaderIncluded: Indicates that the application provides the IP header for outgoing datagrams", so i thought what the reason for error is the last function argument. (also author said what he tried to change socket type to raw). But last argument can be true or 1 (checked this), so error reason is socket type. Also remember what you need admin privileges to run this code.