# Why I get mono-io-layer-error (10022) when try to get the ReadTimeout property on a NetworkStream?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, network-programming

I have a Unity project. When I try to get the ReadTimeout propery of a NetworkStream object, I get the exception with the message "mono-io-layer-error (10022)" on some android devices (only some android devices, many of them doesn't throw exception)

```
[Message]: mono-io-layer-error (10022) 
[Type]: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException 
[StackTrace]: 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.GetSocketOption (System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionLevel optionLevel, System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionName optionName) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.get_ReadTimeout () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

A part of my code

```
public static byte[] ReadAByteCluster(Stream str, int count)
    {
         int timeout = str.CanTimeout ? str.ReadTimeout : 20000;
         TheRestofThecode();
    }
```

Comment: according to e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664668/why-do-i-get-socketexception-10022-when-setting-socketoptionname-headerincluded) you might only be allowed to do this on a raw socket, not on a stream

Comment: Another problem might be that you might be closing the stream before you read the timeout. Could you paste another bit of the code where you create and pass the stream to `ReadAByteCluster()`?

Comment: I am sure that the stream is not closed. When I put it into a try catch block the rest of the code (read data from the connection) works. @FilipVondrášek